# How can I add a second parameter to a macro in Clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure, with-statement

I have the following Clojure wrapping macro with 1 parameter:

```
(defmacro with-init-check
"Wraps the given statements with an init check."
[body]
`(if (initialized?)
  ~body
  (throw (IllegalStateException. "GeoIP db not initialized."))))
```

I want to add `ip-version` to it so I can check if just `:IPv6` or `:IPv4` is initialized. However the parameter does not get passed through when I try this:

```
(defmacro with-init-check
  "Wraps the given statements with an init check."
  [ip-version body]
  `(if (initialized? ip-version)
    ~body
    (throw (IllegalStateException. "GeoIP db not initialized."))))
```

When I use it like this, I get "no such var" at the "if-let [location..." line:

```
(defn- lookup-location
  "Looks up IP location information."
  [ip ip-version]
  (with-init-check ip-version
    (if-let [location (get-location ip ip-version)]
  {:ip ip
   :countryCode (.countryCode location)
   :countryName (.countryName location)
   :region (.region location)
   :city (.city location)
   :postalCode (.postalCode location)
   :latitude (.latitude location)
   :longitude (.longitude location)
   :dma-code (.dma_code location)
   :area-code (.area_code location)
   :metro-code (.metro_code location)})))
```

How can I get the `ip-version` to the `initialized?` function?

Comment: Here's the code online so you can see the context:
https://github.com/sventech/clj-geoip/commit/e4a9a2c4801b13143ea7f3270232d03eb419308d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unquote it with `~`:

```
(defmacro with-init-check
  "Wraps the given statements with an init check."
  [ip-version body]
  `(if (initialized? ~ip-version) ; unquoted with ~
     ~body
     (throw (IllegalStateException. "GeoIP db not initialized."))))
```

Deducing from your docstring, you probably also want to allow multi-expression bodies and unquote-splice them in a `do` expression:

```
(defmacro with-init-check
  "Wraps the given statements with an init check."
  [ip-version & body] ; multi-expression bodies with &
  `(if (initialized? ~ip-version)
     (do ~@body) ; unquote-spliced with ~@
     (throw (IllegalStateException. "GeoIP db not initialized."))))
```